# Merging Activities in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have three different activities which extends three different things and i want to implement multi level inheritance so that i can add it in android:name of androidmanifest.

Here are all activities. I don't know native development at all. Any help would be appreciated.

1st activity

```
package com.package
import hrx.plugin.monet.MonetApplication
class CustomApplication : MonetApplication()
```

2nd activity

```
package com.package
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

3rd activity

```
package com.package;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService;
class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
      override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
      }
      override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
      }
}
```

Comment: An Activity cannot be in an hierarchy with an Application. These are two completely different things, and they are specified in different elements in the XML manifest.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake in question but is there any workaround for combining activities ?

Comment: It’s not really clear what you’re trying to do with Activities. You have more than one distinct Activity class? Why do you need them to be in an hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have three different activities

Actually, you seem to have two different *Application* objects and *one* Activity. If you don't know the difference you may want to go back and take some Android 101 courses.

> i want to implement multi level inheritance so that i can add it in android:name of androidmanifest.

OK. Well you have

```
class CustomApplication : MonetApplication()
```

and

```
class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback
```

Looking [at the definition of `MonetApplication`](https://github.com/HrX03/monet/blob/main/android/src/main/kotlin/hrx/plugin/monet/MonetApplication.kt) we see that it's defined as

```
open class MonetApplication : FlutterApplication()
```

So `MonetApplication` *is* a `FlutterApplication` so if you extend `MonetApplication` you are effectively also extending `FlutterApplication`, so you can basically merge your two existing classes into one:

```
class HighlanderApplication : MonetApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
      override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
      }
      override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
      }
}
```

Now you can use `HighlanderApplication` in your manifest and get all the logic that was in both.